# What does this function do in c++?

Tags: c++, function

This is a question in the book: "Data Abstraction & Problem Solving with C++" 

I wonder what this recursive function performs on given integer array?

```
int mystery (const int array[], int k, int l, int h)
{
    if(array[l]==k)
       return 1;
    else if (l==h) 
       return -1; 
    else 
       return mystery(array, k, l+1, h);
}
```

Comment: the 1/-1 makes me think its some kind of sort function, and its recursive

Comment: did you run it and step through it and find out? did you try writing out a few executions on paper? The first line of the function is a really, really big clue.

Comment: I think this is a fair question, but doesn't the book explain it?

Comment: Steps to figure out a function like this: 1. Identify that it's recursive (calls itself). 2. Determine the base cases, which mark the end of the recursion (in this case, the first two conditional branches). 3. Determine the difference between each recursive call (in this case, that `l` is increased by 1).

Comment: This function is susceptible to [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since no bounds checking is performed prior to accessing elements of `array`.

Answer (score 4):

This algorithm would search array for k. "l" seems to be an index to traverse an array and "h" seems to the index of last element of array.

If element is found in array it would return 1 else -1.

In short a **recursive version of linear search**...

Comment: Also, `h` is the index of the last element, one less than the size of the array.

Comment: More precisely, it searches for the value `k` in `array[l..h]`.